# Вопрос по настройке bootstrap блоков

Tags: bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста. Я хочу, чтобы у меня было еще два блока, но с правой стороны. Там, где я отметил черной линией. Чтобы разделялось справа так же, как и слева. Я прописал свойства для правой стороны, а почему-то не разделилось. Не могу понять. Хочу, чтобы у ряда был блок col-md 3 ; col-md-6, col-md-3 . Слева, посередине, справа. И таких хотя бы два ряда. Но не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
/*ЦВЕТ И ОТСТУП СНИЗУ ДЛЯ БЛОКОВ*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.head-block,
.top-menu,
.top-material,
.left-sidebar,
.right-sidebar,
.content {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
/*ВЫСОТА ШАПКИ*/

.head-block {
  height: 150px;
}
/*ВЫСОТА МЕНЮ*/

.top-menu {
  height: 30px;
}
/*ВЫСОТА БЛОКА ВАЖНЫЕ МАТЕРИАЛЫ*/

.top-material {
  height: 200px;
}
/*ВЫСОТА САЙДБАРА И БЛОКА КОНТЕНТ*/

.left-sidebar,
.content {
  height: 300px;
}
.right-sidebar,
.content {
  height: 300px;
}
/*ГРАНИЦА У КОНТЕНТА*/

.content {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
.top-menu {
  background: #daf2fe;
}
.top-menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Главная</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="css/dopstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 head-block"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 top-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Услуги</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">О нас</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 top-material"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 left-sidebar"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 content"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 right-sidebar"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 left-sidebar"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 content"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 right-sidebar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас присутствуют блоки справа, Вы не видите разделения из-за невидимой границы.
Для отображения границы Вам нужно добавить `border-right: 1px solid #fff;` для блока `.content` в строке 43 приведенного Вами css, т.е.:

```
.content {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Результат:

```css
/*ЦВЕТ И ОТСТУП СНИЗУ ДЛЯ БЛОКОВ*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.head-block,
.top-menu,
.top-material,
.left-sidebar,
.right-sidebar,
.content {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
/*ВЫСОТА ШАПКИ*/

.head-block {
  height: 150px;
}
/*ВЫСОТА МЕНЮ*/

.top-menu {
  height: 30px;
}
/*ВЫСОТА БЛОКА ВАЖНЫЕ МАТЕРИАЛЫ*/

.top-material {
  height: 200px;
}
/*ВЫСОТА САЙДБАРА И БЛОКА КОНТЕНТ*/

.left-sidebar,
.content {
  height: 300px;
}
.right-sidebar,
.content {
  height: 300px;
}
/*ГРАНИЦА У КОНТЕНТА*/

.content {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
.top-menu {
  background: #daf2fe;
}
.top-menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 head-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 top-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Услуги</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">О нас</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 top-material"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 left-sidebar"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 content"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right-sidebar"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 left-sidebar"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 content"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right-sidebar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*с учетом `col-md` от 992px для корректного отображения результата Вам нужно воспользоваться опцией fiddle **развернуть фрагмент***

Comment: спасибо вам большое! А еще такой мини-вопросик. Я могу объединить два блока content в середине, в один большой блок? Как я могу это сделать?
И могу ли я менять размеры col-md на своё усмотрение?

Comment: объединить можно, но поясните пожалуйста что Вы хотите получить в итоге (желательно скриншот), размеры col-md менять можете, однако это делать нужно внимательно потому, что изменив их Вы можете нарушить сетку всех элементов которые используют данный стиль.

Comment: вот это в идеале хочется(
http://radikal.ru/big/p6550760hevqv

Comment: @DaniiL337 посмотрите пожалуйста [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/shnk38zy/)

Comment: спасибо большое. Всё как и хотел.